# Prefered cast style from integer to enum QEvent::Type

Tags: c++, qt, casting

I am looking at this Qt's example from the doc http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/statemachine-api.html :

```
bool eventTest(QEvent *e) override
{
    if (e->type() != QEvent::Type(QEvent::User+1)) // StringEvent
        return false;
    StringEvent *se = static_cast<StringEvent*>(e);
    return (m_value == se->value);
}
```

But in the line :

```
e->type() != QEvent::Type(QEvent::User+1)
```

I do not understand the need for an explicit cast here, that is the integer value to `enum Event::Type` because the following also works :

```
e->type() != QEvent::User+1 // no explicit cast
```

So is it better to use an explicit cast and why ?

Thank you.

Comment: In C++, static_cast is the preferrable way, even if it is an implicit conversion.

Comment: true, please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452920/how-to-cast-int-to-enum-in-c

Comment: i have edited the question to clarify it : actually i am asking whether or not i need an explicit cast here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `QEvent::User + 1` is `int`. Casting that result to `QEvent::Type` turns it into `QEvent::Type`, of course, and I'm guessing that that's its original type, as well as the type of `e->Type()`.

You're right that the cast isn't needed, although the reason is a bit less direct. In `e->Type() == QEvent::User + 1`, the right-hand side has type `int`, so the left-hand side is promoted to `int` and the comparison is done on the `int` values. Ordinarily, that's perfectly okay; that's how `enums` have been used since time immemorial. That cast looks to me like elevating formalism over reality. Some people like to do that.

Answer (score 0):

From the online documentation on [enum](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)

> There are no implicit conversions from the values of a scoped enumerator to integral types, although `static_cast` may be used to obtain the numeric value of the enumerator.

So, yes, you need an explicit cast for such conversions.

But even if `QEvent::Type` is not a scoped enum and allows for an implicit conversion, `static_cast` is a good way to do it.

Please read this FAQ: [What good is static_cast?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/style-and-techniques#static-cast)

Comment: But QEvent::Type is not a scoped enumeration and it's also working without the explicit cast

Comment: I am not familar with Qt and I assumed it was a scoped enum becaues of the `::`.

Comment: Ok but `e->type()` already returns a `QEvent::Type` enum value and we are comparing it also to a valid value of the enum.

Comment: Are `QEvent::Type`, `QEvent::User` and `e->type()` of the same type?

Comment: `QEvent::Type` and `e->Type()` yes whereas `QEvent::User` is one of the possible value of the `QEvent::Type` enum that is defined in the `QEvent` class

Comment: This info was not present in the question. Now it is clear. No need for casting.

Comment: Indeed i have assumed some Qt's background but the info is here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html