# std::vector<int> to std::vector<enum>

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have an array `std::vector<int>` and an `enum class Foo : int`. Is there a better way to cast or convert than a `reinterpret_cast`?

```
std::vector<int> v;
auto& c = *reinterpret_cast<std::vector<Foo>*>(&v);
```

Comment: Why cast the container instead of the elements? I am not sure you can use `reinterpret_cast` the way you are in this example.

Comment: If `reinterpret_cast` works, it's only because you are getting lucky.  Cast when accessing individual indexes.  Or make a copy of the vector and copy over each element and cast one at a time.

Comment: There is an algorithm function designed for this called `std::transform`.

Comment: Thanks, good to know!

Comment: `std::vector<Foo> fv; std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(fv), [&](int n) { return n_converted_to_a_Foo;});` -- That in a nutshell is what you probably wanted.  It would create a new Foo vector based on the `v` vector's contents.  If this is acceptable, I could post this as an answer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie that is the *only* acceptable approach in this case. Can't use the original vector as-is, a copy must be made, otherwise the code has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://godbolt.org/z/M6ofkF

Combine a `static_cast` with `std::transform`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

enum class Foo : int {
   A = 0,
   B = 1,
   C = 2,
   D = 3,
   E = 4,
   F = 5
};

std::vector<Foo> convert(std::vector<int> const &in) {
  std::vector<Foo> out;
  out.reserve(in.size());

  std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), std::back_inserter(out),
                 [](int n) { return static_cast<Foo>(n); });
  return out;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  std::vector<Foo> c = convert(vec);

  assert(c[3] == Foo::E);

  return 0;
}
```

Reference: [How to cast int to enum in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452920/how-to-cast-int-to-enum-in-c)

Comment: Very sadly, this actually does computations (as of gcc12 and Clang13) although the computations do absolutely nothing and it should be optimized to a simple copy assignment. This fact kind of makes me not want to use enums in the first place if I'm going to put them into vectors...

Comment: The issue with this approach is that values that do not belong to the enum get converted as well. https://godbolt.org/z/crrj6sv1f